# ASP.NET how to reverse List Array

Tags: asp.net, arrays

Hey I have the following List

```
List<int> pos = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < combinedResults.Length; i++)
        {
            if (combinedResults[i])
            {
                pos.Add(i);
            }

        }
```

But It seems like the last array items are the ones I want first displayed so I was wondering how can I reverse the List ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reverse method

```
pos.Reverse();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx#Y400

Alternatively, loop in reverse, or even better, make sure the data is going in the correct way round and you wont have to maintain all these bits and bobs!

Answer (score 5):

Run the loop in reverse:

```
for (int i = combinedResults.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

or reverse the list afterwards:

```
pos.Reverse()
```

Comment: Looping in reverse is really the best solution, as it doesn't add any overhead (or very little). Another alternative is of course to loop backwards when displaying the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Reverse method.

```
Array.Reverse(arranyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just add items to the list using Insert:

```
pos.Insert(0,i);
```

Comment: For arrays in most languages inserting at position 0 is slower than inserting at the end because you need to shift the whole array over.

Comment: agreed, but just using list carries some overhead over an array, and list.reverse has overhead as well.  Really depends on the application, and how many items you expect the array to contain.  For simplicity, you could use the Stack object instead of a list, and then use Stack.pop().

Comment: The main issue with `Insert` isn't that it's slower, it's that it scales badly. The larger the list gets, the slower the inserts gets. Inserting 100 items is about the same amount of work as adding 1000 items. Inserting 1000 items is about the same amount of work as adding 30000 items